# Type 'Chart' is missing the following properties

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to add the data from the endpoint response to my chart but when I try to initialize the chart , it throws an error of "Type Chart is missing the following properties from type any .  How do I fix this error ? thanks in advance ? this is my component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import { Chart} from 'chart.js';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
//import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
//import { Data} from '../../app/Data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

 price = [];
 time = [] ;
 data = [] ;
 chart = [] ;

 constructor(private apiService : ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.dailychart()
    .subscribe((response : any []) =>  {
      console.log(response);
      this.data = response;
    Array.from(response).forEach( x =>{
        this.time.push(x.description);
        this.price.push(x.values) ;  
      })

    this  
      this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {  
        type: 'line',  
        data: {  
          labels: this.time,  
          datasets: [  
            {  
              data: this.price,  
              borderColor: '#3cb371',  
              backgroundColor: "#0000FF",  
            }  
          ]  
        },  
        options: {  
          legend: {  
            display: false  
          },  
          scales: {  
            xAxes: [{  
              display: true  
            }],  
            yAxes: [{  
              display: true  
            }],  
          }  
        }  
      });  
    });  

 }

}
```

This is my service class code , the response logs to the console but won't show on chart after removing the [] in front of the chart instance member in component.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpclient : HttpClient ) { }

    public dailychart() {
       return this.httpclient.get<any>('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `TransactionsComponent`, you initialize `chart` with an array of `any` but in your code, you try to assign an instance of `Chart`. Declared `chart` as type `Chart` and it should work.

```
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    chart: Chart;
```